# rel="nofollow" in social links?

Tags: html, web, redirect

I am using  rel="nofollow" in social links is this increase my hit counts or social websites i have used like this

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" ></a>`

is this okay to use this to refer other sites from our site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make search engines ignore the link and it won't be tracked.
That's the right way to do when you make an external link unless you explicitly want the search engines to link the referred website.